# Using Angular to set style to display: none broken in IE 10, works elsewhere

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, internet-explorer-10

I have the following mvc code:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State, Model.States, new {  @class = "form-control", 
        // Displays if the country is United States
        style="display:{{State_Display()}}", 
        Name="State"})

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.State, new { @class = "form-control", 
        // Displays if the country is not United States
        style="display:{{Province_Display()}}", 
        Name="Province"})
```

EDIT: I guess I should mention that Province_Display() is a method in my angular controller that either returns the string "none" or "block" depending on the country chosen.

In the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox, this does what you'd expect: if the user picks united states from a different control, the State field is shown and the Province field hidden.

In IE 10 however, both controls display all the time. Inspecting the elements with f12 in IE, neither of them have any style property at all.

The way I'm thinking of solving this would be to use angular to apply an additional CSS class to the elements instead of using angular to dynamically update the inline style, but my question remains:

Why does this work in Chrome and Firefox but not IE? What's being handled differently? Why doesn't anything appear for Style when I inspect in IE? If you know, will my CSS class idea actually fix the issue (before I bother reworking things)? I'd like to understand the cause so I can avoid similar situations in the future. Thanks!

Additional info:

Right-click, view page source (same in both chrome/IE):

```
<select Name="State" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The State field is required." id="State" name="State" style="display:{{State_Display()}}">
<input Name="Province" class="form-control" id="State" name="State" style="display:{{Province_Display()}}" type="text" value="" />
```

Inspect (Chrome):

```
<select name="State" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The State field is required." id="State" style="display:block">...omitted...</select>
<input name="Province" class="form-control" id="State" style="display:none" type="text" value="">
```

Inspect (IE):

```
<select name="State" class="form-control" id="State" data-val-required="The State field is required." data-val="true">
<input name="Province" class="form-control" id="State" type="text" value=""/>
```

Comment: curious how using asp.net and angular together is working for you? In this specific case, using angular/html to build and handle your forms would automatically handle this issue for you. Using asp defeats the purpose of using angular... you're treating it like jQuery.

Comment: Right now my MVC knowledge vastly eclipses my angular knowledge (though even my MVC knowledge isn't too high). Also, some of the mvc autogenerated views place these form-building calls, so it's what I had by default and it was easy to stick with. I'm trying to slowly add little bits of angular functionality as I learn, refactoring as I go. Dynamically swapping the fields was the first thing I tried.

Comment: I'm aware that angular directives exist, and that they would probably be a better fit here than what I have. Writing a simple one is the next thing on my "learning hit list". So while "this isn't the angular way" is helpful long term, it doesn't answer my short term question of "why dis broke?" :)

Comment: please post the definition for your css class, and a sample of the rendered html.  No way to answer your question without those pieces.  the asp template really is irrelevant to your problem here.

Comment: Rendered html added. FWIW, I'm not using a stylesheet to change the display property of these controls (yet). I'm using the inline style in the post above. Inspection confirms that no other stylesheet is changing the display property unexpectedly. It's just that the inline style is present in chrome/firefox and gets stripped in IE.

Comment: check out my answer.  My guess: you have a bad/missing doctype declaration, but I also showed you how to leverage angular's native show/hide directives, which should allow you a bit more flexibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's still really not enough of your code to go by, but there are a few approaches you can take.  The class thing you recommend should work, but there's something in your code we can't see that's causing it to not execute in IE properly. (any errors in your console?) My best guess... you're missing your DTD, or it's set improperly.  Try adding this at the top of your html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

A better approach (still need to ensure your DTD is set correctly) would be to use ng-show/ng-hide: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHide

```
<!-- when $scope.myValue is truthy (element is hidden) -->
<div ng-hide="myValue"></div>

<!-- when $scope.myValue is falsy (element is visible) -->
<div ng-hide="myValue" class="ng-hide"></div>
```

However, if you wish, you can define a css class like so:

```
.hide {
   display:none;
}
```

and just apply that class to whichever input you wish to hide within you application logic.

Comment: The ng-hide directive works great in all cases! I did try adding the doctype before trying ng-hide, and that didn't seem to fix anything. But this seems overall less hacky than my previous approach anyways, and it's moving just a touch towards a more "angularified" method, so that works for me. Thanks!

Comment: glad to help. Think about ditching ASP, and making your MVC .NET code a RESTful data layer to a front-end that's more explicitly controlled by angular.  I've used this approach with many MVC .NET applications in the last 12 months. Haven't looked back since.